# React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My Navbar isn't showing when i start the app

this is the code

```
    <Router>
      <Routes> 
        <Route path='/' element={<Navbar/>,<Products/>
        <Route path='/product-view/:id' element={<Navbar/>,<ProductView/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Comment: in react router dom v6, element renders the component, only one component... wrap them all into one React.fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that you are trying to render multiple components. Valid JSX ***requires*** returning a single node element to render. Wrap each in a `Fragment`.

```
<Router>
  <Routes> 
    <Route
      path='/'
      element={(
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <Products />
        </>
      )}
    />
    <Route
      path='/product-view/:id'
      element={(
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <ProductView />
        </>
      )}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

If you are wanting to consistently render the `Navbar` on multiple routes then a more optimal solution is to create a layout wrapper component that renders nested `Route` components into an `Outlet`.

```
const ProductLayout = () => (
  <>
   <Navbar />
   <Outlet />
 </>
);
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes> 
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} >
      <Route index element={<Products />} />
      <Route path='/product-view/:id' element={<ProductView />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```